# using coma seperated values and inserting it into database in one shot

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a page where there are check boxes getting loaded dynamicaly so i dont know the number of check boxes (maximum of 50) and out of those check boxes users can select any number between 1 to 50 of checkboxes and can submit the form and on the action page i need get the values of all the checkboxes and insert them to database after checking for unoqueness like this

FIRST PAGE (FORM)

```
<?php while($the_DEATA_ARE_90=mysqli_fetch_array($getDOCS_30all)){ ?>
<div class="This_LISy_Lisy678" id="MAINDIV_DELEE<?=$the_DEATA_ARE_90['dcid']?>">
<div class="CHeck_IS_BOC">
<input type="checkbox" name="selecteddocx[]" value="<?=$the_DEATA_ARE_90['dcid']?>x<?=$the_DEATA_ARE_90['name']?>" id="check_docname<?=$the_DEATA_ARE_90['dcid']?>"/>
```

on the action page i am having this code

```
  $selecteddocx = (isset($_POST['selecteddocx']) ? $_POST['selecteddocx'] : '');
 $doocx = array();
 $docxid = array();
foreach($_POST['selecteddocx'] as $value){
    $str = explode("x",$value,2);
    $doocx[] = $str[0];
    $docxid[] = $str[1];

echo=implode(",", $doocx); // i need to print this for some reasons
echo  implode(", ", $docxid); // i need to print this for some reasons
```

i am having this query to insert the coma sepertaed vales into database
i am converting the values of checkboxes into coma seperated values

```
$shaeredata=mysqli_query($conn,"insert into docs (dcid,pid) values ('$dcid','$pid')");
```

i i know i can insert the values into database in one shot like

```
$shaeredata=mysqli_query($conn,"insert into docs (dcid,pid) values ('$dcid','$pid'),('$dcid2','$pid'),('$dcid3','$pid'),('$dcid4','$pid')");
```

but i dont know how to do this as i am having the values in coma seperated (please note pid is same)

if checking of dcid can be done per pid then it will be great what i mean is thet insert only is dcid is not shared with pid (dcid already exists for that pid)

Comment: **Do not** save data as comma separated values

Comment: i am not saving them into database i want them to be inserted individually

Comment: `show create table xxxx` for each table related.

Comment: You have two options for the data save. You can create a table with 50 columns, one for each checkbox. This is a static solution and if your checkboxes change you'll need to change your table format. There are lots of other drawbacks to this design. Second option is to have something like create table checkedBoxes ( userid int, checkBoxId int, checked bool ); and that way you can add/subtract check boxes with new ids. It's more work to select the boxes for a particular user. The design you choose will depend on your particular needs.